# test if spark dataframe column contains 5 digit number

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe chcktck.  It has a column "code" that has datatype string.  It usually only has one value, and that value is usually 5 numbers.  I would like to create a test to check if the "code" column value is 5 numbers.  so I would like it to be 1 if the "code" value is 5 numbers, and 0 if it's anything else.  I'm not real handy with regex, does anyone have a suggestion or another way to do it?  I have my example code below.

```
chcktck.dtypes

[('code', 'string')]
```

data:

```
chcktck[['code']].show()

+-------+
|   code|
+-------+
|  95110|
+-------+
```

code:

```
if len(chcktck[['code']].collect()[0][0])==5:
    1
else:
    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the below code

```
df.withColumn("contains_5digit", 
F.when(F.col('code').rlike("\d{5}"),1).otherwise(0)).show()

+-----+---------------+
| code|contains_5digit|
+-----+---------------+
|95110|              1|
+-----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

String matching would be a little expensive here if you know code column only has numbers, in that case you could use **`length.`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("contains_5digit", F.expr("""IF(length(code)==5,1,0)""")).show()
```